# rsconnect installation failure

Tags: r, shiny

I've tried for ages to install 'rsconnect' with the command

> devtools::install_github('rstudio/shinyapps')
>   but failed with the message below.

Downloading GitHub repo rstudio/shinyapps@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/rstudio/shinyapps/zipball/master
Installing shinyapps
"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/Flora/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpsPtNWD/devtools20343ed16b87/rstudio-shinyapps-4dd3a9d" --library="C:/Program  \
  Files/R/R-3.2.3/library" --install-tests

Error: Command failed (1)

I've tried

> devtools::install_github('rstudio/shinyapps')
>   also, but failed with the exactly same message.

Can anybody help me with this please?
Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: // , What version of R did you use for this? Make sure you have the latest version. 

Also, if you get an error, did it mention a specific package earlier in the command output? 

Have you tried `> install.packages('rsconnect')`?

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
if (!require("devtools"))
  install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/rsconnect")
```

Comment: // , This is what he did, just jumbled into a multi-line entry with a conditional.

Comment: // , Can you comment about additional things he could try? These instructions fail utterly: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html